# MySQL: count matching rows in 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have to count amount of matching rows in 2 different tables and also amount of unique rows in one table from which I count matching rows with another table.

I tried to select columns that I need, but I don't understand how to count matching and unmatching rows:

```
select nastya.v_em, nastya.cdr3aa from nastya 
union all 
select emerson2017.vgene, emerson2017.amino from emerson2017
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some examples, so we can understand better what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INNER JOIN` with conditions to match the columns which you expect to be equal on both tables. The result set will be the matching rows.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.columnA = tableB.columnA AND ...
```

To find the rows which are unique, use a `LEFT JOIN` checking for rows in which the the columns of the second table are not present:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.columnA = tableB.columnA
WHERE tableB.columnA IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> id - Use your table id

using aliase

```
select ns.v_em, ns.cdr3aa, em.vgene, em.amino from nastya as ns, emerson2017 as em WHERE ns.id = em.id
```

OR 
 INNER JOIN

```
select ns.v_em, ns.cdr3aa, em.vgene, em.amino from nastya as ns
INNER JOIN emerson2017 as em ON ns.id = em.id
```